# Google Maps V3: drawing library

Tags: google-maps-api-3, drawing

I love the new Drawing library for Google Maps v3.7, but I have the feeling the documentation is still not complete and I have a couple of questions:

1. [Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools) only mentions the `overlaycompleted` and `{overlay}completed` events, but I've also [found](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html) the `drawingmode_changed` event. Is there a list of events somewhere?
2. Is there a way to getting a reference (object) to the polygon which we are drawing besides waiting until we finish drawing it and using a listener with `overlaycompleted` as is done in the above example?
3. Is there a way can we delete verteces from a polygon, by simply clicking on them? If not, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching here is what I came up with:

1. I could't find any list of events besides [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#user_editable_shapes_events).
2. I couldn't find any.
3. No, it's not possible, but I've put a [request in](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3755) and I've been shown a small [trick](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_editable_polygon.html) which uses a right-click. Unfortunately this didn't work for me as I needed left-clicking.

I hope this helps others

Answer (score 2):

You can call any overlay event on complete like this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(e) {
    //Your magic goes here 
});
```

`overlaycomplete` is like a global event for any overlay, such as markers, polylines, circles and polygons. but if you want to create a listener for an specific overlay, just change `overlay` to your desired overlay: `polygoncomplete`, `polylinecomplete`, `circlecomplete`.

I know this questions is old, but I wanted to share my answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question, but I have some update on this, maybe will help somebody.

1. There are some additional events for editable shapes that could be useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events
2. Also couldn't find solution for this.
3. This piece of code shows how to remove polygon/polyline vertex on left click:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
    if (e.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Add an click event listener for newly-drawn shape
        // and remove polygon vertex if it was clicked
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
            if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
                if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                    var path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
                    path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                    if (path.length < 3) {
                        newShape.setMap(null);
                    }
                }
                if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
                    var path = newShape.getPath();
                    path.removeAt(e.vertex);
                    if (path.length < 2) {
                        newShape.setMap(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Answer 3 really helped me. 7 years after and this is still useful. Almost impossible to find this info. Thanks a lot.